# New to Python, what is wrong with my while loop calculator?

Tags: python, while-loop, calculator

I'm new to Python and I'm writing a calculator. It is meant to allow the user to add as many numbers as they want, I'm using while loops and I have it so that 0 ends the while loop and presents the sum. It won't calculate properly and ends prematurely. Anybody know why? Here is my code:

```
    import keyboard

    print('Lets add some numbers! Press 0 for total!')
    numb = input()
    totals = float(numb) + float(numb)
    while totals == float(numb) + float(numb):
      numb = input()
    while keyboard.read_key(0):
      print('You pressed the 0 key!')
      break
    print(f'Your total is: {totals}')'''
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not checking `keyboard.read_key(0):` until after the first `while` loop ends.

Comment: Oh okay, it should be within the 1st while loop then? I don't really need the second loop do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for 0 input in the first `while` loop. Also, you're not adding each input to `totals`, you're just testing if `totals` is already equal to the doubled input.

There's no need for `keyboard`, just test what the user entered.

```
total = 0
while True:
    numb = float(input("Enter a number, or 0 for the total"))
    if numb == 0:
        break
    total += numb
print(f'Your total is: {total}")
```

Comment: Ahh I see! That makes sense. I'll try that out. Thanks so much!